# AngularJS: add element to array if not already there works before but not after content reload

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have some food-related inputs. A user may select "unit" from a select list and enter a quantity using an AngularUI slider. When a user enters a unit or quantity value for any food, the food and its values are added to an array, `editedFoods`.

My page loads content via http requests when a category header is clicked. The intention of the `editedFoods` array is that it may be used to persist the user-selected values after a content reload.

Currently, an element in `editedFoods` maintains a live connection to its original food element, UNTIL the content is reloaded. Then the changed food element gets treated as a new element and added newly to the array.

When a select or slider is changed, i call `addSelection(food)`. This checks if the food is already in the array, and if not, adds it, by checking the indexOf `food`:

```
 //Add changed food to array 
 $scope.editedFood = [];

 // toggle selection for a given food
 $scope.addSelection = function addSelection(food) {
 var idx = $scope.editedFood.indexOf(food);
  
 // is currently selected
 if (idx === -1) {
   $scope.editedFood.push(food);
 }
```

Right now, this works until the food category gets reloaded. After that happens, it adds a new food element even if a matching one already exists.

## [Here's the Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8jQjEomGByAjyzbtvM51?p=preview)

Why does it not find `food` in editedFood, and add it anew, after the Food content is reloaded? Can I improve this search by searching for something more specific than `food`- e.g the food's unique id (food.uid)- so that this qualifier works even after reload?

Comment: what do you mean by `reloaded`?

Comment: I mean that clicking on a category title runs the function loadFood(), which runs a HTTP request to a JSON file. The content of a food category is totally removed from the DOM if it is not currently selected. On the Plunkr there is only one category of food, but there will be many.

Comment: sounds like you need to set up caching for your data in a service. Read $http docs recarding cache. And should find numerous tutorials that should help

Comment: @Ali I updated my answer with a working plunker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happens because AngularJS injects a unique property called `$$hashKey` on your data and, when you reload your foodList, the resources got via ajax has a different `$$hashKey`.

If you console.log your editedFood (edited after and before reload) you will see this:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
    $$hashKey: "004"
    code: "X 39 2000000"
    final_factor: "0"
    slider: 7
    sorting: "0"
    title: "Nussbrot"
    uid: "56"
    unit: Array[2]
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
    $$hashKey: "00B"
    code: "X 39 2000000"
    final_factor: "0"
    slider: 5
    sorting: "0"
    title: "Nussbrot"
    uid: "56"
    unit: Array[2]
    __proto__: Object
```

Note how the `$$hashKey` differs. That's what make the `indexOf` function doesn't works after reload.

You should implement your own `indexOf` that looks only in the essential property (problably the `uid`).

Edit: You can do like this:

```
myApp.filter('find', function(){
  return function(food, foods) {
    for (var index in foods) {
      if (foods[index].uid == food.uid) {
        return index;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
});
```

And, in your controller:

```
var idx = $filter('find')(food, $scope.editedFood);
```

Don't forget to inject the `$filter` dependency on your controller.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ht1CCQzIxmUUEzivc5V6?p=preview)

Comment: And, as a bonus, I just learned how Angular filters worked. +++, thank you so much for the great answer & working demo.